# How to treat the Seekbar height as without the thumb

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a default Seekbar like this

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/readingPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp">
            <!--Other tools here!-->
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

But I need something like this:

[image]

I want the bound height of my Seekbar is the height of the blue process only, not include the height of the thumb. 
And the thumb should overflow some part of it to the above and below view. How can I do that?